# How to run a Job from a Stored Procedure in another server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, sql-job

Is it possible to run a Job from a stored procedure located in a different server? If so, how?

Comment: It would be much better if you can run the SQL locally. This is definitely going to give you a performance hit having to travel to another server.

Answer (score 3):

So why not consider using

```
exec LINKEDSERVERNAME.msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'Job Name'
```

?

(didn't test it though, maybe *some-unseen-answer* was the same, but erased as incorrect and not working)

There must be enough privileges for linked-server-login to run the job, of course - at least it has to be job's owner.

Comment: rad!, if i use this, will the stored proc that executed the Job will wait first upon finishing the job before the said proc ends?

Comment: User 6675636b20796f752 : No, it won't wait.
msdb.sp_start_job just actually tries to start the job and doesn't care about an outcome.

Comment: Thanks Rad! will actually use this in my implementation today.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can use the evil that is osql:

```
osql -S "Remote Server" -E -Q"exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job 'Job Name'"
```

(Where -E denotes using a trusted connection, you can also specify credentials using [alternative osql syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012%28v=sql.80%29.aspx))

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, is it compatible with SQLServer 2000? Also, is it bad to use it or how come the 'evil' part?

Comment: Or if it's a linked server - just like @Joe Stefanelli said!

Comment: Yep - it's compatible with SQL 2000 - in more recent versions sqlcmd is the tool. The evil bit, to be fair, is just my pov. There are security concerns, it's hard to debug and generally using a database to call external processes isn't a "nice" pattern.

Comment: Well we do have linked servers, was @Joe Stefanelli wrong or why would he erase his answer? He erased before I could test it!

Comment: @Badger how exactly do you use the osql notation? I can't just execute it as a normal query can I?

Comment: Yep, sorry, to run it from tsql you'll need to wrap it in an xp_cmdshell call. E.g. execute master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'osql ... etc