# schedule sql job in another server via stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, schedule, sql-job

Here is a picture of how things are supposed to work.

I'll log into sql server and manually start `jobA`. My interaction ends here. This job doesn't have a schedule enabled. Hence it is manually started. It has 3 steps. The 3rd step will execute another job manually (which is on another server). Technically the 3 step should in turn schedule `jobA`, to run say after 5 minutes (only 1 time).

But how to schedule `jobA` which is on another server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is better for jobB to wait for 5 minutes and then start jobA (without scheduling).

Assuming it is SQL Server 2005 or newer, You can use [WAITFOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187331.aspx):

```
WAITFOR DELAY '00:05';
```

Or if You insist on scheduling a job using stored procedure, check [sp_add_schedule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187320%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) stored procedure.

If You already knew this and focus of your question is on 'another' server, check: [How to run a Job from a Stored Procedure in another server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573227/how-to-run-a-job-from-a-stored-procedure-in-another-server)